# Why I can't use -> operator when I declare array of object?

Tags: c++, pointers

**Scenery 01:**

```
vector<int> *v = new vector<int>();
v->push_back(10);
```

It works fine.

**Scenery 02:**

```
vector<int> *arr = new vector<int>[5];
arr[0]->push_back(10);
```

It doesn't work. Why?

Comment: Left operand of `->` must be a pointer. `arr[0]` is not a pointer, it's `std::vector<int>`. You need to use `.` instead of `->`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`v` is a pointer to a `std::vector<int>` object. Thus the `push_back()` function of the vector is not directly available using the `.` notation but can be accessed directly by using the `->` notation, as well as other means.

`arr` is a pointer to a `std::vector<int>` object **array**. By calling `arr[0]` you are grabbing the first element of that array which is a `std::vector<int>` object, and not a pointer. The standard `.` notation should work just fine here.

Comment: *Thus the `push_back()` function of the vector is only available by using the `->` instead of the `.` notation.*. Not exactly. You can also write, `(*v).push_back(10)`.